# Fadeout a button after a click using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to jquery and I am trying to make this code works but no way:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add">Add</button>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button.add").click(function() {
            $(this).after('<div><button class="remove">Remove</button></div>');
        });

        //Remove items from cart
        $("button.remove").click(function(){
            $(this).fadeOut();
        });

    });
</script>
```

When I try adding the following line `<div><button class="remove">Remove</button></div>` after the `add button` in the initial code, everything works properly. Anytime I add new remove buttons using the JS code, it works but i can not remove those buttons.

Kindly help me fix it.

Comment: You need to delegate the click event.

Comment: Use `$(document).on("click", "button.remove" , function(){})` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called event delegation.

You can see it as follows: jQuery loads the whole document object model into a variable or object on page startup. Everytime a jQuery function want to use an element it searches through that variable or object to find it. But with your code, the element is added **after** the variable or object is created and by that jQuery is not able to interact with it, because it doesn't know this element.

A simple solution:

```
$( "#parentDivOrElement" ).on( "click", "button.remove", function( event ) {
    $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

This basically let's jQuery find the element in the current DOM, after the update. You should replace #parentDivOrElement with the correct ID or class.

More about event delegation:
https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$(body).on('click', 'button.remove', function(){
// do something
});
```